# Can FileWatchDog watch a file in AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: java, amazon-s3, file-watcher

I am new to AWS and so i was wondering if a FileWatchDog instance can read changes on AWS S3 bucket file directly or do i need to make a local copy of that file,
and if i have to make a local copy of the file then how do i check for changes in S3 bucket file?